# How get 48000 frames per second in PyAudio?

Tags: audio, buffer, frame, pyaudio, microphone

I created stream

```
CHUNK=48000
RATE=48000
p = pa.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(
    rate=RATE,
    channels=CHANNELS,
    format=FORMAT,
    input=True,
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK
)
```

And I take data from the buffer if the number of frames has reached 48000

```
def get_mic_data(s, num_frames):
while True:
    if s.get_read_available() > CHUNK:
        available = s.get_read_available()
        mic_data = np.frombuffer(s.read(num_frames, exception_on_overflow=False), dtype=np.int32)

        return mic_data, available
    else:
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

But this code doesn't give 48000 frames every second
Sometimes 48,000 frames accumulate in 1.4 seconds, sometimes in 0.4
But I need 48000 frames per second